# Twig and javascript issue

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

I'm building a multimedia management application where users can upload various media types for upload using Sonata Admin Bundle in Symfony2.

In the list of uploaded files, I've added an action called "Embed" to individual items to copy embed script to clipboard when clicked, created the list__action_embed.html.twig and customized the base_list.html.twig adding the following javascript to fire when the embed button is clicked.

```
<script>
$('a.embed_link').click(function(){
var id = $(this).attr('id');
alert(id);
   $.ajax({
      type : 'post',
       url : Routing.generate('vid_for_embed', { multimediaId: id}),
   success : function(r)
       {
          $('#embedmodal').show(); 
          $('.modal-body').show().html(r);
       }
  });

});
</script>
```

here's the list__action_embed.html.twig

```
    <a href="#" class="btn embed_link btn-small" title="{{ 'action_embed'|trans({}, 'SonataAdminBundle') }}" id="{{ object.id }}">
    <i class="icon-film"></i>
    {{ 'action_embed'|trans({}, 'SonataAdminBundle') }}
</a>
```

The javascript is not firing unless when put in list__action_embed.html.twig which means it will write the same code for each record which I dont find too pretty. Is it because the list__action_embed.html.twig doesn't extend the base_template? Is it wise extending the template?

Thanks in advance